# Define variables with changing name in Python "for" loop

Tags: python, for-loop, variables

I am currently trying to define a number of variables as empty lists (equal in quantity to the number of iterations of the loop). So far I've tried the following:

```
for i in [1,2,3]:
        locals()["temp_set_" + str(i)] = []
```

When I try to `print(temp_set_1)` outside of the loop in order to verify the output, I get the following error: `NameError: global name 'temp_set_1' is not defined`

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong at the moment and would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Change `locals` to `globals`, but in general it is not a good idea to dynamically create variables. What is your use-case?

Comment: BTW this works for me with no errors. If you are running this loop from a function and trying to print outside of it, it will not work

Comment: Your `temp_set` has called, it said it wants to be a list one day.

Answer (score 0):

In my mac, with python3.6, it works.

```
for i in [1,2,3]:
    locals()["temp_set_" + str(i)] = []
```

[image: output result]

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. The fact that it works for you doesn't help or solves OP's problem, therefore it is not exactly an answer